# Logstash elasticsearch output plugin - Populating api_key from metadata field does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using the elasticsearch output plugin of logstash to post my events to elasticsearch. I am using the api_key authentication method. It is all working fine until I have the api_key parameter value hardcoded. For Ex:

```
api_key => "xxxxxxxxxxxx:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
```

where Xs resemble id and Ys the api_key generated using the [create api_key security api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/security-api-create-api-key.html).

But in my filter I am adding the value to be passed to `api_key` parameter into a metadata field `[@metadata][myapikey]`. The idea is use that in the output plugin as shown below

```
output {
   elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
            cacert => 'path-to-ca.crt'
            index => "my-index-name"
            api_key => "%{[@metadata][myapikey]}"
            ssl => true
   }
}
```

As per my understanding, this should have worked like it would work if we provided the `index` from a metadata field like `index => "%{[@metadata][some-index-name]}"`. I have used this for index names successfully before.

Not sure why the same implementation does not work for `api_key` parameter. I have made sure using stdout plugin that the metadata carries the right value in it, but still see invalid api_key value message when I run this.

Please help here.

Adding full pipeline config

```
input {
  generator {
    lines => [
          '{"timestamp" : "26/01/2021", "fruit-ID" : "t6789", "vegetable-ID" : "Veg1-1002", "Status" : "OK", "myapikey" : "3p4oIUr-Qxxxxxxx-rA"}'
        ]
    count => 1
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
    
        mutate { 
            add_field => { "[@metadata][myapikey]" => "xxxxxxxxxxx-%{myapikey}" }
            remove_field => ["myapikey"]                    
        }
    
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
            cacert => 'path-to-ca.crt'
            index => "my-index-name"
            api_key => "%{[@metadata][myapikey]}"
            ssl => true
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting stdout value? Of course with sensitive values masked.

Comment: Sure, let me share that in a bit

Comment: {
       "sequence" => 0,
     "@timestamp" => 2021-02-04T15:24:19.701Z,
      "@metadata" => {
        "myapikey" => "3p4oIUr-Qxxxxxxx-rA"
    },
           "host" => "ABCDE",
       "@version" => "1",
     "Status" => "OK",
    "fruit-ID" => "t6789",
     "vegetable-ID" => "Veg1-1002",
      "timestamp" => "26/01/2021"
}

Comment: What is the correct name of the field? In your output you are using `[@metadata][myapikey]`, but your stdout output is `[@metadata][my_apikey]`. Is it a typo? Can you update your question with your full pipeline config?

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a typo. I have corrected it in the above post as well. It is `[@metadata][myapikey]`. Sure, will share the pipeline config in a minute.

Comment: Added full pipeline config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is because the `api_key` setting doesn't support the [sprintf format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#sprintf).

In contrary to the `index` settings which [supports that format](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb#L324), [`api_key` doesn't](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/9465260998a096408997b94e58de12b74c0889b6/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client_builder.rb#L162), so what happens is that Logstash sends the raw value `%{[@metadata][myapikey]}` (without resolving it) as the API key and that obviously fails.

I think the main reason behind this design decision is that an API key, much like a password, is not supposed to be a field that travels in each document.

Comment: Is the format right? From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-api_key) it says that you also need to pass the `id` in the field, using the format `id:api_key`, maybe it is missing the `id`.

Comment: That's not my point. You cannot use the `%{...}` to pass the value for `api_key`, it won't work...  That setting expects a static value

Comment: Perfect, that explains